# Why there are no constant functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For some the question might seem trivial but the concept is new to me and  I have been wondering 
why there are no constant functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support?

Following wiki:

**Def.1)** Functions with compact support on a topological space $X$ are those whose support is a compact subset of $X$.

**Def.2)** $\operatorname{supp}f=:\overline{\{x\in X\;,f(x)\neq 0\}}$

What if we take such function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=0\;,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\operatorname{supp}f=\overline{\{x\in\mathbb{R}\;,f(x)\neq 0\}}=\overline{\emptyset}=\emptyset$ but $\emptyset$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ I think....

Could someone enlighten me? Thank you.

Comment: Where were you told that no constant functions on $\mathbb{R}$ have compact support?

Comment: well, anyway that's the only one there is, $f \equiv 0$

Comment: @Hayden: here for example http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wangzuoq/437W13/Notes/Lec%2030.pdf (12th line)

Comment: Well, I'd beg to differ with the claim, for precisely the example you gave.  But as mm-aops pointed out, it's the only example.

Comment: the statement is very clear : ''there are NO functions'', (such functions don't exists). The real question here is if my counter-example is really correct (i.e  that I followed all definitions correctly and so on).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The author in the article you link to (www-personal.umich.edu/~wangzuoq/437W13/Notes/Lec%2030.pdf) is just being sloppy. He really should have said there are no **non-zero** constant functions with compact support on $\mathbb R$ (and thus $H_c^0(\mathbb R)$.

So yes, your example is correct. The empty set is (tautologically) compact.

Comment: Hi Fredrik. Thank you. Unfortunately it is not the first time I have seen it....Exactly the same statement I found in Bott, Tu, ''Differential forms in algebraic topology''. Cheers

Comment: @user124471 Yep, I've seen it as well. In fact, I was just reading in the book by Bott & Tu a week ago, and had to think about the exact same question as you asked.

Comment: @user124471 I was wondering the same thing! Now I know. Can you include Bott Tu in your question?