# Errata for Bott Tu Differential Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, big-list

My book is Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott of which An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu is a prequel.

I am making this as suggested here [An old "list question" edited to include other points](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/an-old-list-question-edited-to-include-other-points) based on my [rejected edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1208279) of another post containing some mistakes [Some possible mistakes in Bott and Tu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338524/some-possible-mistakes-in-bott-and-tu) much like this one [Errata for Atiyah-Macdonald](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42241/errata-for-atiyah-macdonald)

Please post any others you've found. I'll start.

Comment: I dont think that this is the correct place to start an errata of a book. Also note that "almost every" textbook have zillions of errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I do not think that MSE is an appropriate place to collect errata for published texts.  Collecting such errata is an admirable goal, I just don't think that it is appropriate for this platform.

Comment: @XanderHenderson What about [atiyah-macdonald](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42241/errata-for-atiyah-macdonald) as pointed out [here by postmortes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/an-old-list-question-edited-to-include-other-points?noredirect=1#comment131195_30331)?

Comment: @Masacroso What about [atiyah-macdonald](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42241/errata-for-atiyah-macdonald) as pointed out [here by postmortes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/an-old-list-question-edited-to-include-other-points?noredirect=1#comment131195_30331)?

Comment: Now posted on MathOverflow: [Errata for Bott and Tu Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology](https://mathoverflow.net/q/333127).

Comment: @SeleneAuckland That is MO, not MSE.  The most relevant thread on meta here has [only one answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12701/468350), which has a net score of +10, and which suggests that MSE is not the right place for this.  (Thanks to Martin Sleziak for pointing out that thread on CRUDE).

Answer (score 1):

In page 18 (proof of Example 1.6), they claim "there are no constant functions on R1 with compact support" when they should have said "there are no nonzero constant..." This is confirmed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816281/why-there-are-no-constant-functions-on-mathbbr-with-compact-support).